# I need helping reassigning a number in an array

Tags: smallbasic

n is the variable but that doesn't matter
in this case customer[n]["amount"] = 300
but when i try to add 400, the result shows up as 300400. 
I need help.
Thanks in advance for whoever helps me.

```
textwindow.writeline("How much do you want to add?")
adding = TextWindow.ReadNumber()
trying to reassign the string customer[n]["amount"]
customer[n]["amount"] = customer[n]["amount"] + adding
TextWindow.WriteLine("Your new amount is: " + customer[n]["amount"])
```

Comment: The problem must be with the rest of the program. I just ran this program here without any issues 
    n = 1
    customer[n]["amount"] = 300
    textwindow.writeline("How much do you want to add?") 
    adding = TextWindow.ReadNumber()
    customer[n]["amount"] = customer[n]["amount"] + adding
    TextWindow.WriteLine("Your new amount is: " + customer[n]      ["amount"])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to cast the numbers as integers, try something like:

```
customer[n]["amount"] = customer[n]["amount"]*1 + adding*1
```

Comment: Thanks. I made it easier for the program to read the code by using a Subroutine. I also reassigned my variable because they were mixed up, n was from a previous variable. I reassigned the n as q. the proram ran smoothly afterwards.

Comment: This is a nice solution. One of the big headaches is that SmallBasic seems to always guess wrong when there is any ambiguity between strings and numbers.

Answer (score 0):

The problem must be with the rest of the program. I just ran this program here without any issues

```
n = 1
customer[n]["amount"] = 300
textwindow.writeline("How much do you want to add?") 
adding = TextWindow.ReadNumber()
customer[n]["amount"] = customer[n]["amount"] + adding
TextWindow.WriteLine("Your new amount is: " + customer[n]["amount"])
```

somewhere else in the program you must be defining the amount as a text. Then the result will come out as the two texts appended. Just like "Jelly" + "Jam" come out as "JellyJam"